# Ocultar un 'div' desde otra vista con jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

A continuación, os muestro el código con las vistas **"Titulación"** y **"Portada"** además del código jQuery del botón **"nuevo"**

Código HTML 5 (Grails)

Vista: **"Titulación"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="layoutPlantilla">
    <title>Titulación</title>

    <!-- Enlaza los estilos de los ficheros '.css' -->
    <asset:stylesheet src="estilosGeneracionGuiasDocentes/estilosCabeceras.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="estilosGeneracionGuiasDocentes/validaciones.css"/>

    <!-- Enlaza el codigo de ficheros jQuery -->
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQuerySelectores.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryBotones.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryMensajes.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryAjax.js"/>

    <script>
        var enlaceObjetos = {
            urlTitulacion: "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectTitulacion")}",
            urlAsignatura: "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectAsignatura")}",
            urlValidaGuia: "${createLink(controller:"GuiaDocente", action:"validaGuiaDocente")}",
            urlBusquedaGuia: "${createLink(controller:"MenuGuiasDocentes", action:"index")}"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <g:if test="${session.getAttribute("e-mail")}">

        <form id="idFormTitulacion">
            <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                <div class="row content">

                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">
                        <h1>Titulación</h1>
                        <hr>

                        <!-- Titulacion -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="titulacion">Titulación</label>

                            <!-- Muestra mensaje de error si no se selecciona en el select 'titulacion' -->
                            <label class="error errorTitulacion" for="titulacion"></label>

                            <select id="titulacion" name="titulacion" class="form-control select">
                                    <option value="" hidden>Seleccione opción...</option>
                                    <option value="vacio"></option>
                                <g:each in="${consultaTitulacion}" var="indice">
                                    <option>${indice}</option>
                                </g:each>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Asignatura en espanol-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="asignatura">Asignatura</label>

                            <!-- Muestra mensaje de error si no se selecciona en el select 'asignatura' -->
                            <label class="error errorAsignatura" for="asignatura"></label>

                            <select id="asignatura" name="asignatura" class="form-control titulacion select">
                                    <option value="" hidden>Seleccione opción...</option>
                                    <option value="vacio"></option>
                                <g:each in="${consultaAsignatura}" var="indice">
                                    <option>${indice}</option>
                                </g:each>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- curso academico -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cursoAcademico">Curso académico</label>

                            <!-- Muestra mensaje de error si no se selecciona en el select 'cursoAcademico' -->
                            <label class="error errorCursoAcademico" for="cursoAcademico"></label>

                            <select id="cursoAcademico" name="cursoAcademico" class="form-control select">
                                <option value="" hidden>Seleccione opción...</option>
                                <option value="vacio"></option>
                                <option value="2016/17">2016/17</option>
                                <option value="2017/18">2017/18</option>
                                <option value="2018/19">2018/19</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modalidad -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="modalidad">Modalidad</label>

                            <!-- Muestra mensaje de error si no se selecciona en el select 'modalidad' -->
                            <label class="error errorModalidad" for="modalidad"></label>

                            <select id="modalidad" name="modalidad" class="form-control select">
                                <option value="" hidden>Seleccione opción...</option>
                                <option value="vacio"></option>
                                <option value="Presencial">Presencial</option>
                                <option value="Semipresencial">Semipresencial</option>
                                <option value="A distancia">A distancia</option>
                             </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <button id="botonNuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo</button>
                <button id="botonBuscar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>

            </div>

        </form>
    </g:if>
</body>

</html>
```

Vista: **"Portada"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Portada</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="layoutPlantilla" />

    <!-- Enlaza los estilos de los fichero '.css' -->
    <asset:stylesheet src="estilosGeneracionGuiasDocentes/estilosCabeceras.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="estilosGeneracionGuiasDocentes/validaciones.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="estilosGeneracionGuiasDocentes/estilosToast.css"/>

    <!-- Enlaza el codigo de los ficheros jQuery -->
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQuerySelectores.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryBotones.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryMensajes.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryTextos.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryAjax.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryToast.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="javascriptGeneracionGuiasDocentes/jQueryPaginacion.js"/>

    <script>
        var enlaceObjetos = {
            urlTitulacion: "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectTitulacion")}",
            urlAsignatura: "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectAsignatura")}",
            urlValidaGuia: "${createLink(controller:"GuiaDocente", action:"validaGuiaDocente")}",
            urlInsercionPortada: "${createLink(controller:"GuiaDocente", action:"insercionPortada")}",
            urlIdGuiaDocente: "${createLink(controller:"GuiaDocente", action:"idGuiaDocente")}"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <g:if test="${session.getAttribute("e-mail")}">

        <form id="idFormPortada">
            <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                <div class="row content">

                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">
                        <h1>Portada</h1>
                        <hr>

                        <!-- Titulacion -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="titulacion">Titulacion</label>
                            <select id="titulacion" name="titulacion" class="form-control portada">
                                    <option hidden>${titulacion}</option>
                                <g:each in="${consultaTitulacion}" var="indice">
                                    <option>${indice}</option>
                                </g:each>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Asignatura en espanol-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="asignatura">Asignatura en español</label>
                            <select id="asignatura" name="asignatura" class="form-control">
                                    <option hidden>${asignatura_esp}</option>
                                <g:each in="${consultaAsignatura}" var="indice">
                                    <option>${indice}</option>
                                </g:each>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Asignatura en ingles -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="asignatura_ing">Asignatura en inglés</label>
                            <input id="asignatura_ing" name="asignatura_ing" class="form-control portada" value="${asignatura_ing}" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <!-- Curso academico -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cursoAcademico">Curso academico</label>
                            <select id="cursoAcademico" name="cursoAcademico" class="form-control" >
                                <option hidden>${cursoAcademico}</option>
                                <option>2016/17</option>
                                <option>2017/18</option>
                                <option>2018/19</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modalidad -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="modalidad">Modalidad</label>
                            <select id="modalidad" name="modalidad" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden>${modalidad}</option>
                                <option>Presencial</option>
                                <option>Semipresencial</option>
                                <option>A distancia</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="btnHabilitado" hidden>
                    <!-- boton indice -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonIndice">Indice</button>

                    <!-- boton guardar -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonInsertar">Guardar</button>

                    <!-- paginacion -->
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1">Anterior</a>
                            </li>

                            <!-- pagina actual -->
                            <li class="page-item active">
                                <a href="#">1</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="opcAsignatura">2</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a href="${createLink(action: "descripcionAsignatura")}">3</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a href="${createLink(action: "requisitosPrevios")}">4</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a href="${createLink(action: "objetivos")}">5</a></li>

                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a href="#" class="opcAsignatura">Siguiente</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div id="btnDeshabilitado">
                    <!-- boton indice -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonIndice" disabled>Indice</button>

                    <!-- boton guardar -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonInsertar">Guardar</button>

                    <!-- paginacion -->
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1">Anterior</a>
                            </li>

                            <!-- pagina actual -->
                            <li class="page-item active disabled">
                                <a>1</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item disabled"><a>2</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item disabled"><a>3</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item disabled"><a>4</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item disabled"><a>5</a></li>

                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a>Siguiente</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </g:if>

    </body>
</html>
```

Código jQuery (botón **"nuevo"**)...

```
//--- boton nuevo ---
    $("#botonNuevo").click(function () {

        //Borra todos los errores mostrados en pantalla
        $("label.error").text("");

        if(compruebaSeleccioneOpcion() === true && compruebaSeleccionBlanco() === true){

            URL = enlaceObjetos.urlValidaGuia;
            validaGuia = $("#idFormTitulacion").serialize();

            //peticion ajax para validar la guia docente
            peticionConDatosCallBackAjax(URL, validaGuia, function (data){

                if(data.toString() === ""){

                    //si no existe la guia docente, se accede al formulario
                    window.location.href = '/GuiaDocente/index' +
                        '?titulacion=' + opcionTitulacion +
                        '&asignatura=' + opcionAsignatura +
                        '&cursoAcademico=' + opcionCursoAcademico +
                        '&modalidad=' + opcionModalidad;

                }else{

                    var mensaje = " La guía docente seleccionada ya existe.";
                    showDialogo(mensaje);
                }
            });

                return false;
```

Quiero que al pulsar el botón **"Nuevo"** de la vista **"Titulación"** me redirija a la vista **"Portada"** y me oculte el `<div id="btnDeshabilitado">`

**NOTA:** La redirección de la vista **"Titulación"** a la vista **"Portada"**, funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con otra vista?

Comment: Me refiero que al pulsar el "botón 1" (vista 1), me redirija a la vista 2 y me oculte el "botón 2".

Comment: Tu html de tus vistas?

Comment: He modificado prácticamente todo el contenido de la pregunta. Os muestro las dos vistas y el código jQuery. Disculpen las molestias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general, cuando queremos modificar el contenido o apariencia de una página desde otra, necesitamos una forma de comunicarlas. A mi juicio, la más práctica es el hash.

El hash de una URL es lo que viene después del símbolo #:

```
http://misitio.com/preguntas_frecuentes.php?orden=alfabetico#pregunta1
```

Usualmente el hash sirve para indicarle al navegador que queremos que nos dirija a un elemento determinado de la página. En el ejemplo de arriba, queremos que nos dirija al elemento con la ID pregunta1:

```
<div id="pregunta1">
    <h1>¿Qué es un hombre?</h1>
    <p>Una miserable pilita de secretos.</p>
</div>
```

Peeero, resulta que podemos leer el hash de una URL desde JavaScript muy fácilmente, así que podemos aprovecharnos de esta *feature* para resolver tu consulta.

**En la vista Titulación agregamos un hash al final de la URL:**

```
                //si no existe la guia docente, se accede al formulario
                window.location.href = '/GuiaDocente/index' +
                    '?titulacion=' + opcionTitulacion +
                    '&asignatura=' + opcionAsignatura +
                    '&cursoAcademico=' + opcionCursoAcademico +
                    '&modalidad=' + opcionModalidad +
                    '#ocultar-boton';
```

**En la vista Portada leemos el hash y decidimos si ocultar el botón:**

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash == '#ocultar-boton') {
        $("#btnDeshabilitado").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tu solución ha funcionado a la perfección, ha hecho exactamente lo que yo quería. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer todo en un mismo documento. Si es como yo entendi que queres hacer, pone en un div toda la Vista1 y en otro la Vista2, cuando el documento carge ocultas la Vista2 con la fucion hide() de jQuery y cuando se haga click en el boton **Nuevo** mostras(show()) la Vista2 y ocultas la Vista1, o no, y el boton.

Answer (score 0):

Podés poner un cookie desde jQuery, usando js-cookie
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Al presionar el botón pones el cookie.

```
Cookies.set('boton', 'presionado');
```

En la vista portada buscas si el cookie existe. Y si existe ocultas el div.

```
var botonPresionado = cookies.get('boton'); 
if(botonPresionado == 'presionado')  {
   // aca ocultamos el div
}
```

Y, ante el evento en que el div debería estar nuevamente disponible, borras el cookie.

```
Cookies.remove('boton', { path: '' });
```

El código no esta testeado asi que puede fallar. Pero algo así tambien te podría funcionar
suerte!